# How to create an invoice for magento downloadable product?

Tags: magento

I have an problem with invoice generating for my downloadable product.

I tried to create an invoice. But it shows like this error message **Cannot create an invoice without products**.

Can any one help to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meaning that you have not selected the products that you need to invoice if you look at the code that gives this error in following file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php:88:                Mage::throwException($this->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
```

you see that this error is given when no items are found

```
            $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys();
            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($savedQtys);
            if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
            }
```

and you can also see that the items are looked from your post

```
    /**
     * Get requested items qty's from request
     */
    protected function _getItemQtys()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice');
        if (isset($data['items'])) {
            $qtys = $data['items'];
        } else {
            $qtys = array();
        }
        return $qtys;
    }
```

meaning that you have not selected or posted whatever needs to be posted to this method.